# Remote procedure call fails when the execution plan is included

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-execution-plan

I have a very bizarre error here I can't get my head around.

The following T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #Contribs ( ID VARCHAR(100), Contribution FLOAT )
INSERT INTO #Contribs
EXEC [linkedserver].[catalogue].[schema].LocalContrib
SELECT * FROM #Contribs
```

creates a simple temp table in my server, fills it with data from a linked server and views the data.

When I run the remote procedure on its own, it provides me a list of (text,float) pairs.

When I run the whole T-SQL without requesting the actual execution plan, it shows me this list of pairs correctly inside the temp table.

When I run the whole T-SQL **along with its actual execution plan**, it fails and returns me the message 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition'.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do about it? It seems perverse to me that the display of the execution plan should interfere with the execution of the statement itself. It's rather annoying because I wish to examine the execution plan of a parent stored procedure that contains this code. I don't know what the procedure 'LocalContrib' being called looks like on the inside and I'm running SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue, see [this Connect page](https://www.beta.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/772113/insert-exec-remoteproc-with-actual-execution-plan-causes-error-s). They claim it's fixed in "the next service pack", but I can't find a description of it in the SP2 fix list. It might be in a CU, or else it's going to be SP3. No official workaround.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, good find. Rather frustrating bug though!